# AWS EventBridge Custom event doesnt trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have implemented AWS EventBridge custom event and I want to test the rule is working.I use testing utility Of Event Bus as per the image. It said the event is successfully delivered. But I am not able to see in the target( in my case the target is Lambda)

[image]

I want to use the test utility to send the event in EventBridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the payload you are using in the EVENT DETAIL area is wrong.
The payload for that should NOT include source, resources etc.
Just place the pure payload. In your case:

```
 {
    "name": "toyota",
    "address": "test address",
    "country": "uk"
 }
```

If you like more on this, please check. This explains the rule, pattern, etc more clearly.

https://youtu.be/VeF5hQ0gVkA